# Getting error while running selenium grid

Tags: selenium-webdriver

When using my code:

```
    DesiredCapabilities caps = new DesiredCapabilities(); DesiredCapabilities.chrome(); 
caps.setCapability(CapabilityType.BROWSER_NAME, "Firefox"); caps.setPlatform(Platform.WINDOWS); 
caps.setCapability(FirefoxDriver.MARIONETTE, value); 
WebDriver driver = new RemoteWebDriver(new URL("localhost:4444/wd/hub"), caps); 
driver.get("google.com"); 
WebElement element = driver.findElement(By.name("q")); 
element.sendKeys("BrowserStack"); 
element.submit(); 
System.out.println(driver.getTitle()); 
driver.quit();
```

I am getting the following error:

```
 Unable to create new remote session. desired capabilities = Capabilities [{platform=WINDOWS}], required capabilities = Capabilities [{}]
    Build info: version: '3.0.1', revision: '1969d75', time: '2016-10-18 09:48:19 -0700'
```

In selenium console window, and in command prompt I  got this error :

```
    Unable to create new instances on this machine.                                                                                                                                                                                  18:01:04.489 INFO - Driver class not found: com.opera.core.systems.OperaDriver                                                                                                                         18:01:04.490 INFO - Driver provider com.opera.core.systems.OperaDriver is not registered                                                                                                                                        
18:01:04.499 INFO - Driver provider org.openqa.selenium.safari.SafariDriver
registration is skipped:                                                                                                                             
registration capabilities Capabilities [{browserName=safari, version=,
platform=MAC}] does not match the current platform VISTA                                                                                                
2017-01-06:1142)                                                                                                                                              
at
java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)                                                                                                                                              
... 1 more                                                                                                                                                                                                              
18:01:11.703 WARN - Exception: The best matching driver provider
org.openqa.selenium.edge.EdgeDriver can't create a new driver instance for
Capabilities [{platform=WINDOWS}]                                                   
Build info: version: '3.0.1', revision: '1969d75', time: '2016-10-18 09:48:19
-0700'
```

Could you please tell me where is the problem in my code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are setting chrome capabilities `DesiredCapabilities.chrome();` and in next lines Firefox capabilites `caps.setCapability(CapabilityType.BROWSER_NAME, "Firefox"); caps.setCapability(FirefoxDriver.MARIONETTE, value);`

What driver do you even want to create?